# Issue with RedirectUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to prevent the user from using the `RedirectUrl` to access a different website unless the website url is in my database table `RedirectLinksTable`.

> Rules:
>
> 1. User can use `RedirectUrl` and navigate to a new page if that url exists in my database table `RedirectLinksTable`.
> 2. If the Url does not exist in my database table, then it loads my `landing page`.

**Current Results:** If the user passes in a Url using the `RedirectUrl`, it loads the landing page. The issue occurs when the user passes in a Url that exists in my database table. The code doesn't realize that it can use the `RedirectUrl` and send the user to that specific website.

> **`RedirectUrl` is being used as follows:**
>
> ```
> localhost/ProjectName/Login?RedirectUrl=http://www.websitename.com
> ```

**Method checking if the Url is in `RedirectLinksTable`**

```
public ApiResponse<Status, bool> IsRedirectInDatabase(string url)
{
    if (url == null)
        return new ApiResponse<Status, bool>(Status.Success, false);
    
    if(!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
        return new ApiResponse<Status, bool>(Status.InvalidData, false); 

    // Additional code here that doesn't affect the Redirect Issue....
}
```

**Database Table Definition**

***RedirectLinksTable***

```
- Id
- RedirectUrl
```

> What am I doing wrong with my `IsRedirectInDatabase` method?

**Fix**

After further research, I found that my error was with my UI. I had a method with the following line of code:

**Original**

```
return new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Login", new { RedirectURL = HttpContext.Page.Request.Url }))
```

**I changed it to this**

*You'll notice that I had to tack on the `IsAbsoluteUri` to my return statement*

```
return new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Login", new { RedirectURL = HttpContext.Page.Request.Url.IsAbsoluteUri }))
```

Comment: What happens if the URL exists in your database? Are you being redirected to that URL or facing some error message? @Code Chaser

Comment: @AtanuRoy yes, if the URL exists in the database then we redirect that user to the website.

Comment: How are you sure your mistake isn't elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is with the `IsRedirectInDatabase` method since it checks for the Url in the database.

Comment: I am not seeing any database check code in your `IsRedirectInDatabase` method. You are just checking if the URL is well-formed or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well if you're really sure it's in these 4 lines,remove them and it should work :)

Comment: Okay, @loli thanks for challenging me to look elsewhere in my code... I instantly thought it was in my API, but after further research I found the issue in my UI. See my updated post to see the fix!